# Ubuntu 22.04 (Intermittent DNS name resolution failures + gnome-shell freezing after sleep)

Tags: upgrade, 22.04

Upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 - which was rock solid stable to 22.04 and experiencing a couple of issues I am not able to resolve.

Note: system packages fully up to date and using 5.15.0-46-generic

**Intermittent DNS name resolution failures:**

- This is being observed from Firefox + Chrome (latest/stable) whereby sites load, then all of a sudden I will get "DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN", refreshing the page, or waiting a couple of seconds, the sites will be accessible as expected.
- Also observed when pinging a hostname, randomly from the terminal I get "temporary failure in name resolution" although network-manager is correctly configured with my DNS servers.

Already (1) reinstalled Chome/Firefox, (2) checked /etc/resolv.conf, and can confirm the configurations look pretty much the same as I had on 20.04.

**syslog contains lots of:**
systemd-resolved[88108]: Using degraded feature set UDP instead of UDP+EDNS0 for DNS server
Using degraded feature set TCP instead of UDP for DNS server

**gnome-shell freezing after sleep:**

- This issue I am observing is not only limited to when my laptop returns from sleep, on one occasion I was working and the gnome shell froze up, I could only move the mouse. I went into the terminal by using CTRL+ALT+F2 and found the gnome-shell process using 200% CPU. I killed the PID and I was able to go back into the GUI and things started working again.

Any advice will be appreciated. At the moment my mind is telling me to reinstall 20.04 but I'm hoping someone will have some insight into these issues which I haven't attempted yet.

Thnx!

Comment: Please ignore, issues resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Details related to the resolution of the problems experienced:

**Intermittent DNS name resolution failures:**
The cause of the issue I could only assume was due to a compatibility issue on a 3rd party VPN client. I checked the VPN documentation and the client is only supporting 20.04 and not 22.04. I reverted to a previous version of the VPN client and the intermittent DNS name resolution failures no longer occurred.

**gnome-shell freezing after sleep:**
The cause of the issue I could only assume was due to a leak on either the netspeed, or systeminfo gnome extensions. After analyzing the logs I found during the period the shell would freeze or come back from sleep the logs would be flooded with errors related to the extensions. I disabled and deleted the extensions and freezing of the gnome-shell no longer occurred.